# Utah state tax for 401K income of a part-time resident

Tags: united-states, 401k, state-income-tax, utah

We have about $48,000 Social Security income annually and will receive about $36,000 401K income by the end of next year.  We will stay in Utah for the first 3 months next spring and then move to Illinois to live with our children.

How do we owe the Utah state tax next year?  Do we only owe tax for (3/12) * $48,000 of the Social Security income?  How about the tax for our 401k income that we will receive while we are not in Utah?  Will we also owe Utah tax for (3/12) * $36,000 of the 401K income even if we do not receive it while we are in Utah?

Comment: Is that going to be a permanent move to Illinois?

Comment: It will be our long-term plan to live about 7-9 months in Illinois and 3-5 months in the spring time in Utah from next year on.  Our Social Security incomes come monthly, but we only receive our 401K incomes by the end of the year.

Comment: Are you a resident of Utah or a resident of Illinois? where are the cars registered? where do you vote?

Comment: We are currently residents of Utah, but we plan to treat Illinois as our domicile after we move to live most of our time with our children.  In that case, we will be only part-time residents of Utah.